# regex for email in spark dataframe column in java

Tags: java, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to test regexp for spark. I am confused as it works for some regex and fails for others.

In the below code, I am trying to find a match using regexp.
However, it does not return anything. what am I missing?

I have validated the regex there is no issue with it.

```
package com.hsec.correlation;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test {
    public static SparkSession spark;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkStructuredStreamingTest")
                .master("local[2]")
                .getOrCreate();
        // code
        StructType structType = new StructType();
        structType = structType.add("id", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("email", DataTypes.StringType, false);

        List<Row> nums = new ArrayList<Row>();
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("1", "abc@dec.com"));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("2", "adHODFSOIHC9ds"));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("3", "kcbc@dec.com"));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("4", "nnmp@let.net"));

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(nums, structType);
        String query="(email REGEXP '(\\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.com)')";
        df=df.filter(query);
        df.show();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+
| id|email|
+---+-----+
+---+-----+
```

Expected:

```
+---+--------------+
| id|         email|
+---+--------------+
|  1|   abc@dec.com|
|  3|  kcbc@dec.com|
+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in pyspark but following expression seems to get the expected result.

```
 data = [{"Mail": 'adHODFSOIHC9ds'},
            {"Mail": 'kcbc@dec.com'},
            {"Mail": 'abc@dec.com'},
            {"Mail": 'nnmp@let.net'}
            ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    
    expr = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\.com$"
    df = df.filter(df["Mail"].rlike(expr))
    
    df.show()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, replacing \w with [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-] fixed the issue.
seems spark does not understand \w

Answer (score 0):

use below query query strings to make it work.

```
String query = "email  REGEXP (\"[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.com\")";
```